# Movie15 \includemovie problem : file attached blank icon

Tags: beamer, movie15

I am using movie15 package to embed a mpeg video in my beamer presentation.

My viewer is qpdfpresenterconsole (https://launchpad.net/~lissyx/+archive/ubuntu/qpdfpresenterconsole-ppa). It enables viewing embedded videos under Linux Ubuntu (which is not the case of evince…).

The problem is that the output pdf (compiled with PdfLaTeX) contains a "blank icon" representing the file attached.

I found no way to remove this picture, even if I try to use poster option or even an image as text option.

```
\frame[c,plain]
{
    \begin{center}
    \includemovie[text={\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{picture.jpg}}]{.8\textwidth}{.8\textheight}{video.mpeg}
    \end{center}
}
```

Maybe I use a wrong combination of options but whatever option I use, the output looks always the same (we can see the image in the background):
[image: Pdf output with the image on the background]

Have you ever faced the same problem ? Any suggestions to get rid of this annoying icon ?

Answer (score 1):

Command option `attach=false` might help.